# SED Replace string surrounded by spaces with a new string

Tags: sed

I am a beginner in scripting...

I have a file containing a several pages of text. And I wanted to change a word, in the middle of a line, by two others, as in this example:

Original line:

```
 BUREAU DES DOCKS ET TRANSPORTS         POSTE M.G.           CN
```

Modified line:

```
 BUREAU DES DOCKS ET TRANSPORTS         POSTE M.G.           CN NICOLAS
```

To do this, I used 'SED', in this script, with this syntax:

```
while read var1 var2
do
sed -i -e "/POSTE M.G./ s/ $var1 / $var1 $var2 /g" /exploit/scripts/file-MOD.txt
done < liste_MOD
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works for me.  Can you show what doesn't work for you?

```
bjb@rhino:~$ cat /tmp/mod
CN NICOLAS
bjb@rhino:~$ cat /tmp/sed.in
BUREAU DES DOCKS ET TRANSPORTS         POSTE M.G.           CN 

bjb@rhino:~$ while read var1 var2; do sed -i -e "/POSTE M.G./ s/ $var1 / 
$var1 $var2 /g" /tmp/sed.in; done < /tmp/mod
bjb@rhino:~$ cat /tmp/sed.in
BUREAU DES DOCKS ET TRANSPORTS         POSTE M.G.           CN NICOLAS 

bjb@rhino:~$
```

I would use this as the address for the substitution though:

```
/POSTE M\.G\./
```

Otherwise it will match things like `POSTE MAGA`, `POSTE M9G2`, etc.

Also, to match whole words without requiring the spaces before and after, you can use \b:

```
s/\b$var1\b/$var1 $var2/g
```

Comment: Hello Brenda,  there si no subtitution when a use this synthaxe. I can see on screen that the substitution is on, but when a look into the file, it's not.  + 0< liste_PSF
+ read vpsf vpsfn
+ read vpsf vpsfn
+ sed -i -e '/POSTE M\.G\./ s/ QV / QV QUAGLIERI /g' /exploit/scripts/file-MOD.txt
+ read vpsf vpsfn
+ sed -i -e '/POSTE M\.G\./ s/ JR / JR RAFFAI /g' /exploit/scripts/file-MOD.txt
+ read vpsf vpsfn
+ sed -i -e '/POSTE M\.G\./ s/ RS / RS REPELLIN /g' /exploit/scripts/file-MOD.txt

Comment: OK I found the problem: $var1 is the last word, just after there is a endofline.